# Angular shared service not updating values

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with an auth service where i'm handling the user state like so -

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService extends HttpService<User> {

    private readonly _user: BehaviorSubject<User>;

    public user$: Observable<User>;

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, 'users');
    this._user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
    this.user$ = this._user.asObservable();
    }

    signIn(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.path + '/login', { email: email, password: password})
        .pipe(map(user => {
        if (user && user.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            this._user.next(user);
        }
        return user;
        }));
    }
}
```

Now this in my sign in component this works fine and the user is successfully returned -

```js
export class SignInComponent {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    signIn(email: string, password: string): void {
    this.auth.signIn(email, password).subscribe(user => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);
    }, error => {
        this.failed = true;
        this.loading = false;
    });
    }
}
```

However in the component I'm redirected to after the sign in the user observable is null -

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.authService.user$.subscribe(user => {
            console.log(user); // <- the user here is null!
        })
    }
}
```

If I refresh the browser the user object is successfully returned.

I assumed you could share data this way between components but it appears this isn't the case. How would I achieve this?

I should also say the sign in and dashboard components are in different modules.

Answer (score 1):

> However in the component I'm redirected to after the sign in the user observable is null

probably because its `ngOnInit` runs *after* `user$` emitted. You need a **ReplaySubject**, not a **BehaviorSubject**.

BTW, you can replace your `map`

```
.pipe(map(user => {
    if (user && user.token) {
        //...
```

with `tap`, will make the `return` statement unnecessary.

Comment: The point of the `BehaviourSubject` is to return an already previous emitted value. There is no need to use a `ReplaySubject` in his case. In comparison to `BehaviourSubject` the `ReplaySubject` lets you replay multiple emitted values instead of the last one.

Comment: Ok I'm thinking there's something else going on as the ReplySubject isn't emitting anything in my DashboardComponent. Even when I try and get the `.value()` of my BehaviorSubject in the same component it's still null. But is fine after the page reload.

Comment: @"the subject isn't emitting anything" - and the code gets there? POST returns an object, and that object has a `token` property?

Comment: The issue turned out to be that the `AuthService` was a defined in the providers of my `AuthModule`. Moving this to the `AppModule` fixed the problem.